Pose not flipping well
I have this rig, it works great. However, I think I built it facing the wrong way on the axis and now need to rotate it for animations
(Don't worry about the bone sizes)

When I try to copy the pose and paste X flipped, this is what happens. I don't even know what it's doing here. I want to say it's flipping along an unintended axis due to the model's orientation


I tried to rotate the rig by selecting the root bone and rotating 90* in Object Mode. Then I pressed Ctrl A > All Transforms. However, pasting the pose flipped X still looks the same as before even though the model should now be oriented for poses to flip along the X axis


What in the world is wrong with my animation flipping?
Thank you for any help
